# Mysql count for every month

Tags: php, mysql, date, count

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id      level      time
1         1     2014-02-19 04:33:04
2         1     2014-03-19 04:33:04
3         1     2014-03-20 04:33:04
4         2     2014-03-21 04:53:04
5         1     2014-07-19 04:33:04
6         2     2014-07-19 04:33:04
7         1     2014-07-19 04:33:04
8         1     2014-08-19 04:33:04
```

I wanted to get the results for level 1 like this:

```
level1count    year    month
  0            2014      1
  1            2014      2
  2            2014      3
  0            2014      4
  0            2014      5
  0            2014      6
  2            2014      7
  1            2014      8
  0            2014      9
  0            2014      10
  0            2014      11
  0            2014      12
```

I tried this query , but does not give result for every month

```
SELECT YEAR(time) AS year, MONTH(time) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count FROM users where level = '1' GROUP BY year, month
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to have all months in result they exist or not exist in database,for the result set you need to have all months in query like union ,then left join with your table with year and month based conditions

```
select coalesce(sum(`level` = 1),0) level1count
 coalesce(sum(`level` = 2),0) level2count ,y,m
from
(select 1 as m,2014 as y
union
.
.
.
union
select 12 as m ,2014 as y
) months
left join t on(months.m = month(t.time) and months.y = year(t.time))
group by months.m, year(t.time)
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e71c/10)

A better approach than union would be to have a table that contains all of your months with year rows and then join it with you table

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(level = 1) as level1count, 
       year(`time`) as year, 
       month(`time`) as month
from your_table
group by year(`time`), month(`time`)
```

Comment: Count for every month is not coming. Some months are missing.

Comment: @mirzavu is there data for the missing months?